# Text to speech API for IOS in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

Text to audio API works fine on Android and windows but not for iOS / Mac.

Is there any way to check the device type and use an alternative of mp3 for iOS?

```
 const playAudio = async () => {
    if (props.currentA !== props.key) {
      props.setCurrentA(props.key);
      setLoading(true);
      const audio = await convertTextToVoice(props.text);
      let audioSrc;
        audioSrc = `data:audio/mp3;base64,${audio}`;
      
        setAudio(audioSrc);
        setLoading(false);
        setPlaying(true);
       }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem for quite a while and the solution was pretty simple. Mp3 api does not work for IOS. So we have to use wave.
But for this we have to first check the device type and then use the API accordingly , so this is what I did:

```
 const playAudio = async () => {
if (props.currentA !== props.key) {
  props.setCurrentA(props.key);
  setLoading(true);
  const audio = await convertTextToVoice(props.text);
  let audioSrc;
  const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    // Convert audio to WAV format for iOS
    const wavAudio = convertToWav(audio);
    audioSrc = `data:audio/wav;base64,${wavAudio}`;
  } else {
    // Use MP3 format for Android and other platforms
    audioSrc = `data:audio/mp3;base64,${audio}`;
  }
  
    setAudio(audioSrc);
    setLoading(false);
    setPlaying(true);
   }
```

};